# Does github have a option to display HTML code like a compiler

Tags: html, github

I know that for Jupyter notebook you can get stuff compiled like - https://github.com/ctgk/PRML/blob/63499fffa5c19ec58ece35ed51692ff64112e4dd/notebooks/ch01_Introduction.ipynb where we use .ipynb.
But, since I am kinda new to Github I don't know if there is an option like that in HTML since when you do .HTML only code comes. I wanna do this code: https://github.com/QuantzLab/QuantzLabWebsite/tree/main/Auth%20Files%20-%20PHP. I am a contributor to that repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub will not render your HTML for you on their site. You'll need to clone the repo and use a web browser to render the file